# How can I create a checkbox function on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a checkbox for my project but it is not outputting.
Below is a sniper of my code

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MaterialApp> {
  bool _myBoolean = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Checkbox(
        value: _myBoolean,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _myBoolean = value; // rebuilds with new value
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please do assist me on this

Answer (score 2):

Hi  you were almost there : just add `!` to value so *isChecked = notValue*

like this :

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MaterialApp> {
  bool _myBoolean = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Checkbox(
        value: _myBoolean,
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            _myBoolean = value!; // WILL rebuild
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```